# К какому типу относятся методы в C#? Reference type or Value type?

Tags: c#

Все классы, структуры, массивы и делегаты - ссылочный тип.
Value Type включают большинство встроенных типов
(в частности, все числовые типы, тип char и тип bool), а также
пользовательские типы struct и enum.

К какому типу относятся методы? Определяется по возвращаемому значению я так понимаю? Если void, то null, если int, то Value Type, right?

Comment: Методы вовсе не являются объектами, поэтому не обладают типом.

Comment: Да, а структуры являются значимыми типами (value type), а не ссылочными.

Comment: @VladD да, спасибо, структуры значимый тип, запутался маленько, спасибо за ответ